# Can't compile typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create tns plugin that uses 3rd party native plugin.

I managed to use 3rd party native plugin in application directly following this.
http://developer.telerik.com/featured/using-native-libraries-in-nativescript/

How can I use api in tns plugin.

1. I cloned https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-plugin-seed
2. I created platform/android/include.gradle
3. added to include.gradle

   ```
   android {
   productFlavors {
       "nativescriptcardview" {
           dimension "nativescriptcardview"
       }
   }
   }

   dependencies {
     def supportVer = "22.2.0";

     if(project.hasProperty("supportVersion")) {
      supportVer = supportVersion
     }

    compile 'hanks.xyz:smallbang-library:0.1.2'
   }
   ```
4. tried to call it from plugin.android.ts like this.

   ```
   import {Common} from "./plugin.common";
   import * as app from "application";

   export class Plugin extends Common {
     bangThis(args) {
       var mSmallBang = new xyz.hanks.library.SmallBang.attach2Window(app.android.foregroundActivity);
       mSmallBang.bang(args.object.android);
     }
   }
   ```

But tsc does not compile `plugin.android.ts(7,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'xyz'.`

Comment: Ok I figured it out.
Definition was needed. like this
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-fresco/blob/master/nativescript-fresco.android-map.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Definition was needed. like this

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-fresco/blob/master/nativescript-fresco.android-map.d.ts